# Why was Atticus trapped?

Tags: iron-druid

In the book *Trapped*, it's quickly revealed that all the links to Europe save one are severed, and Atticus has to bind his apprentice to the Earth in Europe, and so Atticus' only option is to shift to the one good spot, which is risky.

What I don't get is... Why? I mean, from what else was said, anywhere in Europe would suffice for binding her, and they had fresh, clean mortal identities, so why not just take a plane somewhere safe in Europe?

Even if they couldn't take a plane, surely shifting to the one spot and then leaving that region for another would've been safer?

Comment: Sort of recall that they were afraid the whole pantheon was in on it & getting on a plane when Zeus/Jupiter was against you was thought to be a "bad idea".

Comment: No, I don't recall that at all, do you have a quote?  Also, see my edit.

Comment: Sorry, can't find that book. The next one, _Hunted_, definitely has a discussion about the Morrigan telling them they had to go by foot. It occurred to me I may have been thinking about Percy Jackson, though.

Answer (score -1):

Ok Atticus wants to bind his apprentice.  As shown below he must do this on the Eurasian plate.  According to the rangers all of the normal tethers that allow druids to shift around in the Eurasian Plate (Europe) have been disabled save the one near Mount Olympus.  This is obviously a trap since it’s an Olympian god (Bacchus) that’s trying to kill him.  Atticus’s problem is if he goes to the one working tether (Mount Olympus) he’s confining himself to a small area (Bacchus’s followers can “smell” magic and therefore track him).  In addition and I don’t know if this is a spoiler but “someone” is supplying the Olympians with information about his location. Sure he could shift away but that would disrupt the binding of Granuaile. Apparently it takes quite a long time to bind someone and while doing it your rather vulnerable.  Now back to your question as to “why”.  If Atticus were to do as you suggested, shift to an area not affected and then use some other more mundane way of getting to the Eurasian Plate for the binding he’d still be vulnerable and more likely worse off.  While in a plane, car, train, etc, a druid is cut off from the earth (where they draw their strength and magic). If they were to say run in on foot they would be exposed for a much greater period of time out in the open.  Sure they’d still have their magic but due to the tethers being disabled they would not be able to instantly escape by shifting away.  The followers of Bacchus could still track him if he came from the outside and whoever was supplying the Olympians with information about Atticus would still be supplying it.  Atticus is “trapped” figuratively and literally.  Come from the outside and lose your ability to shift. Shift to the one working tethers and limit yourself to a smaller area that’s much easier to search.  It’s really just a question of which bad choice should Atticus pick and of course you’ve read the book so you know what he ultimately does. I hope this was a better edit of my previous answer.  I’m still new to this :)

> “She is not yet bound to the
>   earth,” Brighid noted, seeing no
>   tattoos on Granuaile’s right arm.
>   “No, but she is ready. I was on
>   my way to begin the process when
>   we were interrupted.”
>   “On your way where, if I may
>   ask?”
>   “I was searching for an
>   appropriate place in Arizona.”
>   Brighid frowned. “You cannot
>   bind a Druid to the earth in the
>   New World.”
>   That set me back on my heels a
>   bit. “You can’t?”
>   Brighid seemed as bemused as I was. “It may be done only in
>   Europe. Only the Eurasian plate
>   has agreed to participate in the
>   ritual. I thought you knew this.”
>
> “Majesty, perhaps the shuddering
>   of Gaia reported by the Iron Druid
>   may explain some recent disturbing
>   reports coming in from the rangers
>   throughout Europe.”
>   “Do share with us all,” Brighid
>   said.
>   “Most tethers to Europe from Tír
>   na nÓg are now inoperable. The
>   death of the Slavic plane may
>   explain this.”
>   “Begging your pardon,” I said. “Are you saying that it’s impossible
>   to shift to Europe right now?”
>   The fop raised an eyebrow and
>   sneered at me. “That is precisely
>   what I am saying. Except for a
>   small area in the south of Greece.”
>   “The tethers for the rest of the
>   world still work?” Brighid asked.
>   “Yes, Majesty.”
>   “And the secret paths walked by
>   the Fae?”
>   “Those still function admirably.”
>   “So your theory is that the death
>   of Perun’s plane is causing this.”
>   “It is a possibility.”
>   “Where, precisely, in Greece may
>   one still travel freely?” I asked. “Anywhere in the vicinity of
>   Mount Olympus.”

Comment: This doesn't add any information that wasn't in my question. My question was precisely, that given that only one tether was available, why use it instead of traveling somewhere else and using mortal conveyance to get where they need. Your answer asks the same question.

Comment: Well that's what I get for trying to answer this at work. I'll re-edit my answer better shortly. :)